# PHPUnit installed via Composer uses wrong autoload

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I have a normal directory structure:

```
 - root
  - vendor
      - bin/phpunit
  - tests
     - bootstrap.php
```

my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "test/testing",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*@dev",
        "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects": "2.2.*@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["tests/config.inc","test.inc"]
    }
}
```

My bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

There is some other stuff inside the bootstrap, thats why I need it,
but I removed it here because it has nothing to do with my problem.

When I try to run PHPUnit at the root folder:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php tests/ItemsTest.php
```

I get the error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(xxxx/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/tests/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in xxxxxxx/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/tests/bootstrap.php on line 4
```

i don´t know why phpunit/the autoloader is loading this bootstrap:

```
phpunit-mock-objects/tests/bootstrap.php
```

and of course line 4 in there:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpUnit does not understand the bootstrap path as relative for whatever reason.

Replacing the bootstrap path as follows seems to do the trick:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap ./tests/bootstrap.php tests/ItemsTest.php
```

Comment: GREAT! thanks a lot! i didn´t see this between all the trees... ;)